Ensure Javascript factory method executes only once
I am using Tabler Bootstrap template and HTMX. As can be seen in the vertical layout (select it from the 'Layout' menu) of the Tabler preview, on reducing the width of the browser window, the left sidebar collapses and a toggler button with a hamburger icon is displayed to show/hide the sidebar. When using HTMX history (hx-push-url) and HTMX out of band (hx-swap-oob) features for a link, on pressing the back browser button, the toggler button stops working: the sidebar is shown but then is not hidden.
On some investigation, the issue looks to be due to the Tabler factory function being called again on going back:
(function(factory) {
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
  factory();
})((function() {
  'use strict';

  var e = new Map; function t(t) { var o = e.get(t); 
  ...

As the factory function is called again, the event handler for the toggle button click gets registered twice, causing the toggling to be done twice on one click, thus being ineffective.
So to ensure the factory function is called only once, modified it using a global flag (_factoryCreated) as follows:
/**
 * Ensure that `factory()` below is run only once.
 */
var _factoryCreated;
_factoryCreated ??= false; // assign only if null or undefined, i.e. once

(function(factory) {
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    factory();
})((function() {
  'use strict';

  if (_factoryCreated) {
    return;
  }
  _factoryCreated = true;

  var e = new Map; function t(t) { var o = e.get(t);
  ...

This apparently resolves the issue. Is this ok? Is there a better/proper solution, such as resolving the issue in my code instead of in Tabler? Thanks!
